# Underlining nav links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get the underline on my nav to be as long as the `a` element and not the `li` element?

[Example Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xtk0AGDh5jNBtgUm9n92?p=preview)

Comment: It is the same length as the anchor tag. Remember that it has padding on it from Bootstrap by default.

Comment: Thank you, long time since I've done any bootstrap.  Got it sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Drew kindly pointed out, there is default Bootstrap padding.  This fixed it:

```
.navbar-right li a {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```